# What do I do with this on hold post

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, on-hold

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078851/create-a-setup-in-windows-application-along-with-the-database) which is currently on hold as `unclear what you're asking`. I understood what the post and suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3027717). Which I had suspected will be rejected for `changing too much in the original post` so I added this edit summary

> Added more info so that this post can be removed from hold

But yet the edit was rejected.

I don't have up to 2k rep yet so what can i do to help this post be removed from on hold.

Comment: You can wait for the user to reply. We still don’t know which database they’re using, for example, or which installer.

Comment: @minitech Oh. ok but still that doesn't make the post unclear

Comment: Actually, yes. It does. How were you planning on answering it?

Comment: @minitech All he needs to do is put the database in custom actions or Add it as a file to the applications folder when packaging the setup

Comment: So you're arguing that the answers to "which installer" and "which database" are implied by the information/tags given? And that adding the details won't affect or invalidate any currently possible answers?

Comment: @Bart I'm not arguing. Was just making a suggest. Sorry if it seems like I'm arguing though

Comment: Hehe, you're misunderstanding. "Arguing" can also mean "So your argument is that...".

Comment: @Bart Not actually. it might but from the **little** i know an answer will be able to be given with the information in the question. I dont think the post should be `on hold as unclear` (Just a suggestion, Might be wrong as i dont have moderation exprience and dont know so much of so rules)

Comment: "Unclear" does not necessarily mean "I don't understand what the question is". It can also mean "there are not enough details to answer it with complete certainty". If that is still the case, leaving it on-hold until the situation is sufficiently clear is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Bart OK. thanks for the clarification seems like thats what i should have asked for before *arguing* blindly

Answer (score 2):

Submit a comment to explain how the question author can clarify his question (the changes you attempted in the rejected revision), which may then lead to the question getting re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

The question author should have been notified what information was missing. That mostly was just what installer he was using.

Comment: There are comments to point out things like this.